# Data Studio - How to get the average value within a given time frame?

Tags: dataframe, google-apps-script, looker-studio

I have my connector where I'm able to get the spend value within a given time frame (on the request passed to the `getData` it has the `startDate` and `endDate` parameters and the fields with `spend`, all normal). Now I want a card that shows the average spend per day. That would be a field like

```
spend / DATE_DIFF(endDate, startDate)
```

But how do I pass those date values to the formula?

Answer (score 0):

### In order to see the average spending amount instead of the total amount, you need to change your aggregation type from "Sum" to "Average".

Please see here the [documentation](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7193479?hl=en) and the [Apps Script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/data-studio/aggregation-type).

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't apply to my case as the API doesn't return the spend value day by day. Instead it's the whole value for a given time frame.

Comment: Do you have some Apps Script code that show how you get your data? If you implement the getData() request as specified here:  https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/reference#getdata  you can set the fields in the request https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/data-studio/field and set the aggregationType of the field https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/data-studio/field#setAggregation(AggregationType) to AggregationType.AVG

Comment: Once again, thank you. But the API returns the sum already. Sadly I can't share the code with you as it doesn't belong to me.

Comment: It is not easy for me to understand the way you get your data without seeing the code, but if you want to manually set a formula to a field calculate your average value, you can do it with fields.newMetric().setFormula()